# CSS указать градиент

Tags: html, css

всем привет! помогите сделать такой эффект распыления для блока сверху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто линейный градиент с прозрачностью.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно узнал о таком хаке наложении цвета/градиента на блок c `background-image`.

```css
.image
{
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 0%, #FFFFFF 100%), url("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51AEijHJslS._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gradient-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px; 
    display: inline-block; 
}    

.gradient-box::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    z-index: 1; 
}

.gradient-box img {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-box">
    <img src="http://surl.li/mjfuc">
</div>
```

Пример использования background: linear-gradient с использованием псевдоэлемента ::before для наложения его поверх изображения